# estoy intentando crear la validación de un usuario por medio de un login, pero me arroja un error

Tags: mysql, laravel

Soy nuevo en Laravel y necesito que me ayuden con este error, al intentar validar al usuario lo envió a una ruta, anexo mi ruta:

```
Route::post('login',function(){ 
 
//return request()->only('username','password');
$credentials = request();

if(Auth::attempt(['usuario'=>$credentials, 'contrasena'=>$credentials])){
    return 'hola';
}


})->name('post-login');
```

Este siguiente código es mi formulario:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<body>
    <div id="login">
        <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Login form</h3>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                        <form id="login-form" class="form" action="{{route('post-login')}}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <h3 class="text-center text-info">Inicio de sesion</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username" class="text-info">Usuario:</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="text-info">Contraseña:</label><br>
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        
                               
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Iniciar Sesion">
                          
                              <div id="register-link" class="text-right">
                                <a href="{{ route('registrar') }}" class="text-info">Registrate aqui!</a>

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Mi archivo auth.php ya se modifico con el modelo y especifique la tabla

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Usuario::class,
            'table' =>'usuario',
        ],
```

el modelo lo cree yo y también las tablas, anexo mis tablas:

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('usuario', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('idUsuarioA');
            //hasta 30 caracteres
            $table->string('nombre',30);
            $table->string('apellidosP',30);
            $table->string('apellidosM',30);
            $table->string('rol');
            //aqui el correo va hacer unico
            //$table->string('correo')->array_unique();
            $table->string('usuario');
            $table->string('contrasena');
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Mi modelo:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    //tuve que especificar la tabla usuario porque me lo tomaba en plural al quere subir datos
    protected $table = "usuario";
}
```

Este es el error que muestra cuando intento acceder con los datos que ya tengo en la tabla:

```
Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, App\Models\Usuario given, called in C:\Users\aleja\Desktop\proyecto_final\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 415
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentar esto en el modelo User.php yo declaro constantes de cada role

```
const ADMIN = 'ADMIN';
const EDITOR = 'EDITOR';

public function isAdmin() {
    return $this->role === User::ADMIN;
}
public function isEditor() {
    return $this->role === User::EDITOR;
```

Posteriormente hago un Middleware para cada usuario para validar en la vista register agrego un campo oculto;

```
<input type="hidden" name="role" value="{{ \App\Models\User::EDITOR }}" />
```

En la migracion de user agrego el siguiente campo para que se carge  cada rol

```
$table->enum('role', [User::ADMIN, User::EDITOR])->default(User::EDITOR);
```

En lógincontroller puedes agregar lo siguiente para la redirección de cada usuario sea redirijido a dónde tu gustes:

```
public function redirectPath {
   if (auth()->user()->isEditor()){
    return "/home"; o la ruta que quieras
  }
   return "/";
 }
```